# how to display input submit like div?

Tags: css, input, submit-button

suppose i have input type="submit" and i make the input just like div so my code bellow...,

```
<style>
.me{width:200px;height:200px;background:green;text-align:center}
img{width:200px;height:50px;}
</style>

<div class="me">
<img src="mywife.png"/>
Emma Watson
</div>

<form action="marry">
<input class="me" type="submit">
<img src="mywife.png"/>
Emma Watson    
</input>
</form>
```

will make two identical Emma Watson's photos with her name in bottom. And i can click my submit input as normally.

Thanks,

Comment: just use `<input type="image" src="mywife.png" />`

Comment: @TamilSelvan image + text though.

Comment: @all and everything which able to do with div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get exactly the same style, you need to add some extra HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3yT2/1/

HTML:

```
<button class="me abspos" type="submit">
    <span>
        <img src="mywife.png"/>
        Emma Watson
    </span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.me {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
    text-align:center;


    /* I added this */
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}

/* extra code for vertical alignment */
.me.abspos {
    position: relative;
}
.me.abspos span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```